# Why does Rails Active Support deep_dup not make a copy of the array embedded into the object being cloned?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have an object that embeds an Array in its state. I am using `deep_dup` on the object instance but the returned object references the same array object as the original instance, which is not what I was expecting.

Here is what I do:

```
class A
  def initialize(arr)
    @arr = arr.deep_dup
  end

  attr_accessor :arr
end

a = A.new(['a', 'b', 'c'])
# => #<A:0x007fe6eb7ae458 @arr=["a", "b", "c"]> 
b = a.deep_dup
# => #<A:0x007fe6f382ad20 @arr=["a", "b", "c"]> 
b.arr[1] = 'e'
# => "e" 
a
# => #<A:0x007fe6eb7ae458 @arr=["a", "e", "c"]> 
b
# => #<A:0x007fe6f382ad20 @arr=["a", "e", "c"]> 
a.arr.object_id
# => 70314884952600 
b.arr.object_id
# => 70314884952600
```

I have read in the documentation of [`deep_dup`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#deep-dup), that

> The deep_dup method returns a deep copy of a given object.

What am I doing or understanding wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you take a look at the source for [`deep_dup`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/deep_dup.rb), on `Object`

> ```
> def deep_dup
>   duplicable? ? dup : self
> end
> ```

it just calls `dup` (`duplicable?` is always true, by default). Where, for arrays it calls `deep_dup` on every element:

> ```
> def deep_dup
>   map(&:deep_dup)
> end
> ```

Looking at [`dup`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Object.html#method-i-dup) for `Object` (since that's what ends up being called on `A`):

> Produces a shallow copy of obj—the instance variables of obj are copied, but not the objects they reference. dup copies the tainted state of obj.

So, to get your example to work, you'd need something like:

```
class A
  attr_accessor :array
  def initialize(array)
    @array = array.deep_dup
  end

  def initialize_copy(copy)
    copy.array = self.array.deep_dup

    super
  end
end

a = A.new(['a', 'b', 'c'])
b = a.deep_dup
b.array[1] = 'e'

puts a.inspect          # => #<A:0x007f857be2f510 @array=["a", "b", "c"]>
puts b.inspect          # => #<A:0x007f857be2f448 @array=["a", "e", "c"]>
puts a.array.object_id  # => 70105642924 560 (spaces added for clarity)
puts b.array.object_id  # => 70105642924 660
```

The `initialize_copy` method isn't well documented anywhere, but the `dup` method states

> This method may have class-specific behavior. If so, that behavior will be documented under the #initialize_copy method of the class.

So it's set up as a way to customize the `dup` process without actually overriding `dup` and [this](https://apidock.com/ruby/Object/initialize_copy) documentation (which is the only real documentation I can find on that method) shows that it only takes the 1 parameter, which is the copy

Comment: I believe that your answer is 99.9% correct. Firstly, do we need `self.` for the `self.array.deep_dup`? I think simply `array.deep_dup` is enough. Secondly, the `a.array.object_id` and `b.array.object_id` should be different objects at the end, whereas what you have as printed values in your answer implies they are equal. Am I wrong?

Comment: btw, I am trying to learn about `initialize_copy` which I only find in `Array` and `String` class in Ruby API documentation. Where can I find `initialize_copy` documentation for `Object` ?

Comment: `it just calls dup.. where, for arrays it calls deep_dup`. Where is this done? I don't see ActiveSupport overriding Array#dup.

Comment: @lulalala "it [`Object#deep_dup`] just calls `dup`...where, for arrays [`Array#deep_dup`] calls `deep_dup` on every element". Wasn't meaning to imply that `Object#deep_dup` called `deep_dup` on every element in the array as a side effect of calling `dup` on the array. Does that make things clearer?